# Allow for a date to only be used a certain amount of times

Tags: sharepoint-online, date, enforce-uniquevalue

We have a date column that we want to only dates to only be used a certain amount of times.
I know there's a way to enforce unique values, it this would be 5 entries with the same date and after that just tell the user to pick a different date.

Answer (score 0):

There's no out-of-the-box way to accomplish this. For low code, I would recommend the following:

- Create a Microsoft Form where the user can input the information they normally would via the SharePoint list form (including the date).
- Create a Power Automate flow which is triggered by entries to the Microsoft Form. It will determine whether there are over 5 list items with the date entered by the user. If there is over 5 list items with the selected date, then it emails the user to let them know their request has been rejected. If there's not over 5 list items with the selected date, then it adds the item to the list.

The users would only have read access to the SharePoint list.